# Consuming node module in a tar file exposed by team city artifact

Tags: node.js, npm, teamcity

So there is currently a team city server which packages a node module for internal use and exposes it via an artifact. The artifact is a `tar.gz`file which contains `package.json`, `dist/**/*`, `readme.md` files/folders.

In my package.json dependencies (for a dependent package) I have something like:

```
"some-module": "http://some-address/guestAuth/repository/download/some-project/.lastSuccessful/some-module.tar.gz"
```

Which resolves correctly to the tar.gz file, and I can download and open it all fine when doing it manually. However the odd thing is that when I do an `npm install` npm blows up with the error:

```
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Blah\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-10684-84325da0\some-server\guestAuth\repository\download\some-project\.lastSuccessful\some-module.tar.gz
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.3
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Blah\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-10684-84325da0\unpack-f18f9e1b
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno -4075
npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Users\Blah\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-10684-84325da0\unpack-f18f9e1b'
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\Blah\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-10684-84325da0\unpack-f18f9e1b
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.
```

I am super confused as I have tried doing `npm cache clean` and deleting my `temp` folder in the appdata/local nothing seems to stop this error.

I have looked over lots of related issues like:

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6309

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5133

However nothing seems to work, I am on windows 10 64-bit using npm 3.5.3 and node 4.2.6.

Has anyone else achieved the same sort of thing or is there something I am missing here as it is a blocker on a current project and none of us seem to have any idea why its blowing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

So the issue was that I was not putting a containing folder in my tar file, so if you add a root folder and have your package and other files underneath that, it all works.